# SvelteKit app and Wordpress Blog under one domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

I have an AWS EC2 server running with a PHP website and a Wordpress blog in a subfolder, both served with apache.

Structure:

- Website: https://website.com
- Blog: https://website.com/blog

I would like to rebuild the website with Sveltekit and Server-Side-Rendering.

Is it possible to run Sveltekit (most likely as a node-server) together with the blog (still under /blog) on the same server?
Or is there a way to route all request to /blog to a different server where the blog is hosted?

Or is there a completely different approach that i could take?

Cheers.

Comment: What's your webserver? Nginx, Apache? Did be no reason you can't set one up as a reverse proxy for sveltekit

Comment: I use Apache as the webserver.

Comment: "Is it possible to run Sveltekit (most likely as a node-server) together with the blog (still under /blog) on the same server?" -> yes, we run Magento and Sveltekit on the same server under the same domain with some rules in nginx to decide which route goes to Sveltekit and which one goes to Magento. You should be able to do the same with Apache.